# Fine tuning Django queryset retrieval

Tags: django, django-queryset

In a Django app of mine, I need to display, for a list of users (called `user_ids`), their:

`username`, `avatar` and `score`.

The `username` is retrieved from the User model, whereas `avatar` and `score` are present in the `UserProfile` model (that has a one-to-one field point to the `User` model, called `user`).

Currently my approach is to fetch the full objects (see below), even though I just need 3 attributes from the two models.

What's the most efficient way for me to just retrieve just the required fields, nothing else? Now I know i can do:

```
usernames = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids).values_list('username',flat=True)
scores_and_avatars = UserProfile.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_ids).values_list('score','avatar')
```

However, these give me separate querysets, so I can't iterate over them as a unified `object_list` and show each user's `username`, `score` and `avatar` in a Django template. So what would be the most efficient, light-weight way to retrieve and put this information together?

---

Currently, I'm doing the following to retrieve these three fields: `queryset = User.objects.select_related('userprofile').filter(id__in=user_ids)`

Comment: I think this is the most efficient way by using select_related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way it's use [values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#values), your query will look like this:

```
usernames = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids).values('username', 'userprofile__score', 'userprofile__avatar')
```

This solution will return dictionary, but you can try to use [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) instead of values, it'll create django model object with specified fields, but if you will try to access not specified field it'll generate additional query.

```
usernames = User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids).select_related('userprofile').only('username', 'userprofile__score', 'userprofile__avatar')
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. And to be sure, no need for `prefetch_related` here?

Comment: values automatically create join without select_related

Comment: should include `.filter(id__in=user_ids)` in the second suggestion (right now it's querying all objects in the model

Comment: Yes, sorry missed it

Comment: But note that if you will try to access another fields it will generate additional query, so be careful with only.

Comment: With you say another field, you mean any field other than `username`, `userprofile__score` and `userprofile__avatar`, correct? I don't have any other field to access, but I'm wondering whether `only()` is intrinsically more efficient than using `values()`.

Comment: Yes, any field other than username, userprofile__score and userprofile__avatar. Code snippets in answer will generate same query to database, but in situation with values it will automatically make joins and you will recieve dict. In situation with only django will construct full model object and replace fields that you didn't specified in only with defered object, and when it try to access defered field it will make additional query. So only more usable because you can access your fields like in normal object instead of specify key for values dict that sometimes look ugly with lookups

Comment: Also values will work slightly faster because it doesn't spent time for object constructing. But you will see this difference only if you have a really large amount of data.